# What is the difference between a TCS PhD thesis and Computer Science experimental PhD thesis?

Tags: soft-question

I'm doing my PhD in computer science, namely theoretical computer science and currently waiting for my VIVA. I think one of my examiner is an experimental person, how can I convince her that my work have significant contribution similar to an experimental research.

I don't do experiment but I have theoretical contribution for my PhD. Can anyone recommend good literature that give comparison between theoretical and experimental computer science?

Thanks and will really appreciate your kind replies.

Pradeep

Comment: unf there is not a lot of crossover, the two fields are somewhat separated/ distinct currently. some of the most thorough TCS research is in SAT transition point. there are few surveys on experimental TCS in general. there are areas of number theory that have a significant experimental aspect. automated thm proving shows up sometimes, program termination analysis, etc... this question doesnt say anything about what your research actually is on... some more stuff [here](https://vzn1.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/great-moments-in-empiricalexperimental-mathtcs-research-breakthough-sat-induction-idea/)

Comment: At least here in the US, members of the dissertation committee are supposed to be experts in the field in which you did research. So your situation sounds pretty odd to me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. Sometimes here in Malaysia there are chances for the dissertation committee consists of experts from other research area, due to limited number of experts.